# Does intelligent life exist in the galaxy or universe?

Tags: aliens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any proof of alien life?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/is-there-any-proof-of-alien-life)

i am surprise no one has ever asked this on skeptics .. do aliens exist i want to see people support thier answers with proof. And if you disagree you must say why aliens do not exist !

Comment: "i am surprise no one has ever asked this on skeptics ", closed as duplicate. :-) BTW: This is a Q&A site and about applying skepticism — it's for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. So it's not the place for general discussions pro and contra the existence of intelligent extra-terrestrial life.