# Did we receive a signal from outer space in 1977?

Tags: astronomy

This was recently posted on 9gag:

[image]

> In 1977, we received a signal from outer space, which lasted 72 seconds. We still do not know how or whence it came.

Did we receive such a signal in 1977?

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/is-there-any-strong-evidence-of-alien-life

Comment: Yes, we received many signals from outer space in 1977, including from the Viking landers on Mars and the Voyager spacecraft on their way to Jupiter.

Comment: @MarkAdler as wells as many many more, for pulsars and stars and quasars and ...

Comment: Why is there a frog in the picture?

Comment: It is the [small fact frog](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/small-fact-frog) meme.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, there was a famous narrowband signal detected in 1977, which became known as the "Wow! signal". Whether it came from outer space is unknown.

- The original astronomer wrote a [30th Anniversary Report](http://www.bigear.org/Wow30th/wow30th.htm) on the signal in 2007, which covers a lot of the technical details.
- Wikipedia [adequately covers the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal).
- Brian Dunning of the Skeptoid Podcast [examined the evidence](http://skeptoid.com/episodes/4342) in 2012 to give a readable summary. In short, while its origins are unknown, and several conjectures have been rejected, there is no evidence that it came from aliens.

Comment: this wasn't the incident with the microwave? lol

Comment: @Himarm: Nah, the [microwave oven](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-32598767) incident was more recent (past 17 years in Australia), but it illustrates the problem of jumping to conclusions about unknown signals.

Comment: But if it did come from aliens, then they definitely look like blue frogs, right?